# jQuery fails when have Divs of a certain name

Tags: jquery, filter, duplicates

I made a filter that I wanna use across my site for filtering content. 
If I have a content I place on the page twice to effect to separate areas. But when I run the code with both Keys. It doesn't work.

But when I delete one Key, it works.

jQuery:

```
 //toggle for projects page filter
 $("#brand-filter").click(function(){
  $(".Brand").show();
  $(".Print").hide();
  $(".Digital").hide();
 });
 $("#print-filter").click(function(){
  $(".Brand").hide();
  $(".Print").show();
  $(".Digital").hide();
});
 $("#digital-filter").click(function(){
  $(".Brand").hide();
  $(".Print").hide();
  $(".Digital").show();
});
```

HTML

```
 <ul class="filter-key">
     <li class="key-brand" id="key-brand"><a href="#" name="brand-filter" id="brand-filter">Brand</a></li>
     <li class="key-print colour-alpha" id="key-print"><a href="#" name="print-filter" id="print-filter">Print</a></li>
     <li class="key-digital colour-bravo" id="key-digital"><a href="#" name="digital-filter" id="digital-filter">Digital</a></li>
 </ul>
```

Comment: What do you mean by deleting one key?

Comment: @PraveenKumar 

So on mobile, the content loads outside of a slideshow and the page structure is quite a bit different, so I load it in separately. Using a media query, I hide desktop on mobile, hide mobile on desktop. But I use the same key on both. So the 'filter-key' shows on both mobile and desktop. But it will only work if its deleted. Having them both load breaks the filter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the HTML rules, there should be only a single element with an unique `id`. If id's happens to be more than one, the syntax becomes invalid and functionality breaks. So try to replace your `id` either with `class` or `name` or any other HTML `attribute`.

Comment: Ohhhh I am dumb, thank you. So simple.

Comment: If it has solved your issue, request you to accept this as answer.